# Spring rest repository -> How to dynamically omit fields from response

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I have a rest service and the customers want to be able to specify which fields are returned in the endpoint.

I am using `PagingAndSortingRepository` to generate the endpoints from models.

Ex: `http://localhost:8080/users`
Would return

```
{
  name: "John",
  age: 23,
  gender: "Male",
  salary: 25000.0
}
```

They would like `http://localhost:8080/users?fields=name,age,gender` to return..

```
{
  name: "John",
  age: 23,
  gender: "Male"
}
```

I could make a projection but this needs to be dynamic because we have lots of fields.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I dont believe it is supported out of the box, furthermore I trully cannot see any added value in specifying (from the consumer side) the fields to be returned. You will probably have to pass the parameter as a String[] and then write code to use reflection (or something more complex like a static map between the field parameters and the actual field names - to hide your class structure) on the results and just set NULL any field that is not desired. If any sort of security / authorisation is required, you should better create different controller methods with different security anots

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much value doing this way, but if you really want to achieve this, then I have created example Spring boot app on [GitHub](https://github.com/YogenRaii/spring-examples/tree/master/spring-filter-custom-fields).

First, have a model to hold the data and add `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` to ignore the null fields as:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Float salary;
    private String gender;
}
```

Your controller method will be like this:

```
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public User getString(@RequestParam List<String> fields) {
        User user = new User("Yogen", 26, 3000.00f, "male");
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(User.class, field -> {
                    if (!fields.contains(field.getName())) {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        field.set(user, null);
                    }
                },
                field -> {
                    final int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
                    // no static fields please
                    return !Modifier.isStatic(modifiers);
                });
        return user;
    }
```

Here I am using Spring's `ReflectionUtils` to filter the field.

So, your request `http://localhost:8089/?fields=name,salary` will return:

```
{
  "name": "Yogen",
  "salary": 3000
}
```